# Rails: Limiting daily user login count by IP address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

Is there any way to limit a user's login access to only, say, 5 IP addresses daily? Such that if a user account tried to login in the same day from a 6th different IP address, they would be denied. I would like this restriction to reset at the end of the day, however.

If Authlogic doesn't provide a way to track this out of the box, what ideas do you have about how I should implement this? As you can probably tell, I'm already using Authlogic for authentication.

My main goal is to limit my user's ability to share their login with a non-registered user; I know that most people's IP address will change periodically throughout the day because hardly anyone has a personal static IP, but I think 5 is a fair number of allowances, even taking into account that a user may visit my site on their iPhone, or at Starbucks, etc.

Thoughts?

UPDATE: After reading through many of the comments on the link provided by @tadman, I'm thinking that it might be more useful to limit the number of **new** sessions created on a machine that had none previously instead of by IP address. If I understand how Authlogic works, sessions are a combination of server-side records and a cookie in the user's browser, correct? If I "log out" of my site, the cookie is still there in my browser, is it not? Just with an expired value or something like that. Can I test against that? Such that if a computer that doesn't have that cookie at all I would consider to be a completely **NEW** login, and I would limit the number of new logins to 5 a day? Would that be feasible approach?

See this user's comments about rate limiting by IP for an angle on what I mean: http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/#c43031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can track this in a database, a more lightweight solution is to track this using Memcached. This allows you to do other things, like limiting login rates and restricting the number of unique IPs a person may visit from over the course of a given time.

The nice thing about Memcached is it will automatically expire records after a specified period of time. With the database-driven approach you will have to do this yourself.

Example: http://simonwillison.net/2009/Jan/7/ratelimitcache/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but how would I implement this? The example you provided seems to rate limit for a specific IP; I'd want to do it on my User model...?

Comment: You could track the User ID just the same as the IP, or perhaps a combination of both.

Comment: Reading your edit above, I think you might want to track the number of unique sessions per user per day, or something of the sort.

Comment: Yeah, that would be what I would want to do. Can I do this with memchaced, or do I have to use a database approach?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably create a table called sessions, which contains `ip_address, logged_in_at, user_id`.  You'd do something like this when a user logs in:

```
session = current_user.sessions.build(:ip_address => ip_address)
if session.valid?
  session.save!
  redirect_to root_url
else
  redirect_to you_cant_login_url
end
```

In your session.rb, you'd have

```
class Session < AR:B
  belongs_to :user
  validate :hasnt_logged_in_a_bunch
protected
  def hasnt_logged_in_a_bunch
    if self.user.sessions.count(:conditions => ['logged_in_at > ?', Time.now.start_of_day]) > 5
      self.errors.add_to_base("You've logged in too many times")
    end
  end
```

Sorry if this is a bit ugly and isn't valid code, but it should hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like this might impede on what Authlogic does already (not sure, but I don't really want to bother Authlogic if possible). Any thoughts about my question edit above?